# Grouping data to create range columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
Row   Column   Type
1     1        =
1     2        =
1     3        O
1     4        =
1     5        =
1     6        O
2     1        =
```

And I need to get something like that

```
Row   Start_Column   End_Column   Type
1     1              2           =
1     3              3           O
1     4              5           =
1     6              6           O
2     1              1           =
```

I tried to group it, to manipulate with ROW_NUMBER, RANK but with no luck

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, the simplest method is probably the difference of row numbers:

```
select row, type, min(column), max(column)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by row, type order by column) as seqnum_2,
             row_number() over (partition by row order by column) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by row, type, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
order by row, min(column);
```

If `column` is sequential with no gaps, you can simplify this even more:

```
select row, type, min(column), max(column)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by row, type order by column) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by row, type, (column - seqnum_2)
order by row, min(column);
```

Why does this work?  Well, if you subtract an increasing sequence from `column`, then the result is constant -- when the types are the same.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c448b3e776fd1ccbe561659dc9b30ee) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I tried to do it on my data and it works! Thank you! I tried to do something similar, but I didn't even think about grouping the difference between a column and a type number

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LAG()` and `SUM()` window functions to create the groups that you want and then aggregate:

```
SELECT [Row], 
       MIN([Column]) Start_Column, 
       MAX([Column]) End_Column, 
       MAX([Type]) [Type]
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY [Row] ORDER BY [Column]) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 
      CASE WHEN [Type] = LAG([Type]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Row] ORDER BY [Column]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END flag
    FROM tablename
  ) t
) t
GROUP BY [Row], grp
ORDER BY [Row], grp
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=09ffbebd26ba53c91d2df953fbd60db3).
Results:

```
Row | Start_Column | End_Column | Type
--- | ------------ | ---------- | ----
  1 |            1 |          2 | =   
  1 |            3 |          3 | O   
  1 |            4 |          5 | =   
  1 |            6 |          6 | O   
  2 |            1 |          1 | =
```

Comment: It was a bit difficult for me to understand why SUM (OVER ORDER BY) calculate sum of current and all previous items. The idea is pretty simple. The current type corresponds to some number. If the type does not change, the number is the same. The type has changed - we increase the number. Thank you for this implementation)